# USB connection between Android and winlator

Tags: animation, usb, emulation

I have a Android tablet and have installed winlator on it.
It allows me to run windows apps on Android.
And I want to use it for all in one animation setup and for that I will need to connect the container of winlator(windows vm) to Android through a virtual USB connection.

Is there any way I could do that?

I tried searching for it on web but there where no answers.